# iOS Distribution: Can I change the bundle identifier later on, to match it the reverse domain name of my customer?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I am an independent developer (coming from Android). I developed an app for a customer, and used a work title for this project as bundle identifier.

So, now comes the time, where I want to move to testing on a limited amount of devices with ad-hoc distribution provisioning profiles.

For this I need to create an App ID with a bundle identifier. So, my customer will finally want his app distributed under his reverse domain name.

Can I change the bundle identifier later on, to match it the reverse domain name of my costumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundle Identifier (Application Id) is an unique identity for any application. You can change it for any application by creating new Apple Id on developer account any time you want until you upload your application on Apple store.

Once you upload your app on Apple store, You can not change it. As if you change it afterwards you will not able to update your app and it will be considered as a new app with new bundle identifier instead of update of existing app.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can change it anytime.

You can't change the project name in this field in Xcode, however:

[image]

You'd have to rename the whole project to change the last greyed out part of the Bundle ID.

Notice however that you can **never** change the Bundle ID after the app has gotten to the App Store.

Comment: Well, you can. You simply remove the application from the app store, and then resubmit the application as a new app. ;)

Comment: @SergiusGee What exactly do you mean by "has gotten to the App Store"? Is Having distributed the app with ad-hoc profiles "gotten to the App Store"? Or, in other words, when is it time to change from my reverse domain name to my costumers? To make sure, the app can later be distributed under my costumers name?

Comment: @Pavan You are sure about that?